# HERE Points of Interests (POIs) for trucks

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to develop an app with the main focus on truck drivers. I would like to display POIs on map, focused on this group of drivers. From the Here documentation, I can see categories like Truck Repair, Truck-Semi Dealer-Services, Truck Dealership, Truck Parking, Truck Stop-Plaza or Truck Wash.

Is there any way to find if a Fueling Station is adapted to trucks? I am wondering how POIs are choosen in truck mode? Is there any attribute for this? Is there any way to be sure that for example an Emission Testing POI will be suitable for a truck?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Trucks details are not yet available in the HLS Search API. They are available in the Map Places data. We currently provide Truck attributes as premium content.
Eg: TruckParking, Service, DieselWithAdditives etc. Please contact our sales if you are more interested in the premium content. For HLS, truck-specific categories that you find in places categories api are the only ones exposed.